# Why is my three.js code not rendering in my live browser?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm just begun with three.js and I'm stuck as to why the code is not rendering to my Google Chrome browser. I have also enabled WebGL in the Advanced settings. I've left my code below from a simple tutorial. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%};
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        
    
        <script>
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            const animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code itself looks fine. So you probably do not include `three.js` correctly. Can you please replace `js/three.js` with `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js`?

Comment: Omg that was perfect. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, how can I load an image with the load() selector?

Comment: Um, what do you mean with `load()` selector?

Comment: Something like this:     var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().  
load(“assets/stone.jpg”);

Comment: It's probably best if you study the code of this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube